# Yii2: GridView Sorting removed from column header

Tags: gridview, datagridview, yii, yii2, footable

```
[
    'header' => Yii::t('app', 'Price') . ' usd.',
    'contentOptions' => [ 'class' => 'text-right'],
    'attribute' => 'price',
    'format'=>['decimal',2],
    'headerOptions' => ['data-type'=>'number'],
]
```

I need view formatting money, but it removes the sorting link for the column from the header.

I Use footable

Comment: please add more detail what you mean by sort not working if it is about the link removed from the column name for sorting then the answer below will work for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use `label` option instead of `header`

```
[
    'label' => Yii::t('app', 'Price') . ' usd.',
    'contentOptions' => [ 'class' => 'text-right'],
    'attribute' => 'price',
    'format'=>['decimal',2],
    'headerOptions' => ['data-type'=>'number'],
]
```

Comment: is it not sorting when you click on the column name `Price usd` @NikitaShahov i just tested it and it works

Comment: Sorry, I forget say. I use footable initialize for gridview